# Кэширование изображений в Android

Tags: java, android, android-imageview

В приложении при запуске грузятся изображения по ссылкам в `ListView` состоящий из `ImageView`. Каким образом лучше сохранять эти изображения, что бы при повторном запуске заново их не скачивать? Да так что бы не сохранять изображение размеры которого могут быть несколько мегабайт.

`BitmapFactory.decodeStream(in)` сжимает изображения, если да то как можно узнать сколько изображение весит после сжатия.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Для загрузки и кэширования изображений существует множество готовых решений в виде библиотек. Используйте их, не пишите велосипеды:

1. [Universal Image Loader](https://github.com/nostra13/Android-Universal-Image-Loader)
2. [Picasso](https://github.com/square/picasso)
3. [Fresco](https://github.com/facebook/fresco)
4. [Volley](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/volley/)

<s>тысячи их</s>